# Хостинг проектов PHP vs Python Django, с чем это едят?

Tags: django, хостинг

Имею внушительный опыт работы с проектами под PHP.
Поднятие серверов на VDS

- Ubuntu, Debian
- MySQL
- PHP
- Nginx
- Webmin
- ISPManager

Управление всем этим как с панелей так и без.

Вопрос: Через панели например ISPManager можно управлять всем что нужно, хосты, модули PHP, MySQL и т.д. А для настройки работы проектов на Django использую панели? Или поставил сам Django и все? В какой связке такие проекты работают?

> P.S. Для локальной разработки например проектов на PHP я пользовался
>   сперва Денвером, последние 5 лет OpenServer, А что используют для
>   проектов на Django?

Прошу не закидывать помидорами.

Comment: Настоящие мужики берут Ansible/Docker/Kubernetes или аналоги и не играются с этими вашими игрушечными панельками. Не только для Django, а вообще для всего

Comment: @andreymal Просил же без тухлых яиц и помидор... Прям вот не терпится свои железные коко показать да?

Comment: Независимо от того, что мне терпится или не терпится — панели просто не нужны

Comment: «В какой связке такие проекты работают» — nginx + uwsgi/gunicorn, если не рассматривать вопрос развёртывания